# malloc not casting to struct

Tags: c, struct, type-conversion, malloc, declaration

I have the following simple code:

the first usage of the struct, `f` works fine, but I can't malloc for `n` - I get an error that it void* can't be assigned to myValues*. I know I shouldn't cast malloc, so how can I do it? What's wrong?

The exact error:

`a value of type "void *" cannot be assigned to an entity of time "myValues *"`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct values
{
int a;
char c;
void *pv;
values *next;
} myValues;

int main(){
    myValues f;
    myValues *n = malloc(sizeof(myValues));
}
```

Comment: Show the exact error message.

Comment: You used C++ as C.

Comment: Do you know what a type cast is?

Comment: Compile the code with a C compiler rather than a C++ compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is obvious that the program is compiled as a C++ program. Otherwise the compiler would issue an error that the name `values` is not declared for the structure definition.

```
typedef struct values
{
int a;
char c;
void *pv;
values *next;
^^^^^^ 
} myValues;
```

If so you have to write

```
myValues *n = ( myValues * )malloc(sizeof(myValues));
```

because a pointer of type `void *` can not be implicitly converted to a pointer of another type.

(Or you need to rewrite entirely the program as a C++ program for example substituting the call of the function `malloc` for using of the operator `new`.)

Or you should compile the program as a C program. In this case you have to write

```
typedef struct values
{
int a;
char c;
void *pv;
struct values *next;
^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
} myValues;
```

Comment: Better you should recommend `myValues *n = new myValues()` for the C++ case.

Comment: @zwol I thought about this but I decided that it is possible that he wants to compile the program as a C program even when he uses a C++ compiler.

Comment: So basically the problem (using the c compiler) is that the compiler doesn't know `values`? Why is it has to do with the malloc? because malloc is also relating to the objects inside the struct?

Comment: @OferArial The problem is that he is using a C++ compiler for a C program. The program will compile neither as a C program nor as a C++ program.

Comment: I get that, but I don't get why adding `struct` is important. How does malloc has to do with the object inside the struct?

Comment: @OferArial malloc has nothing to do with the undeclared identifier values in the structure definition provided that it is a C program.:)

Comment: So why does the error occured in malloc line, and when I just added the `struct` before values it fixed it?

Comment: @OferArial The program was compiled as a C++ program and in this case the name values is declared.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137302/discussion-between-ofer-arial-and-vlad-from-moscow).

Comment: @OferArial I do not take part in chats.

Comment: @OferArial If you compile the program as a C++ program you have to cast the returned value of the malloc to the type of the pointer in the left side. If you compile the program as a C program you have to specify keyword struct before the name values in the structure definition. That is all.